# How to get an event from testServer using curator?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have written test code about my service.
My code looks like below.

```
        Object obj = new Object();
        service.add(obj); // zookeeper node created in service.add

        Thread.sleep(7000); // wait until it is created

        Boolean created = OtherService.pick(a2, a2); // use node date in OtherService

        assertThat(created).isTrue();
```

In this case, i don't want to use Thread.sleep.
Is there any way to get an event or callback from TestingServer to test whether node is created?? not using thread.sleep ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used latch for the synchronization with zookeeper's node creation.

```
        TreeCacheListener listener = (curator, event) -> {
            switch (event.getType()) {
                case NODE_ADDED:
                    createdLatch.countDown();
                }
            };
        cache.getListenable().addListener(listener);

        Object obj = new Object();
        service.add(obj); // node creation by zookeeper

        // Wait until Node is created
        timing.awaitLatch(createdLatch);

        Boolean created = OtherService.pick(a2, a2); // use node date in OtherService

        assertThat(created).isTrue();
```